# Magento Permissions

Tags: magento, centos, chmod

I have just moved my Magento store from cPanel to DirectAdmin (Centos).

My problem is now with permissions.  Previously on cPanel all folders were set to 755 and files 644.  This worked great.

However on DirectAdmin the only way I seem to be able to get everything to work (including the downloader) is by setting all folders to 777.  Is this safe to do so?

Also what should the User and Group ownership be set to?

Thanks!

Comment: this will depend on how the web server is running usually, weather you are running PHP as an apachemodule, fcgi etc..

Answer (score 1):

Followed this and everything seems to be working well:
http://blog.nexcess.net/2010/12/06/securing-magento-file-directory-permissions/

Comment: http://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/stop-magento-permissions-errors-permanently/ Another post dealing with getting owner/group permissions to let you have file/folder access without errors.

Answer (score 0):

chmod may not be your problem. Who is the owner of the files on new server? Set the ownership via chown to www-data (ubuntu) or whatever they should be on centos. They way you can find this out is by setting all to 777 then look at the some newly created file, from var/log or var/session and see who is the owner/group. Reset back to varien's recommended chmod settings and do the chown user:group on all files.

Comment: I tried this and new files folders get created with apache as the owner.  I set all files/folders to have apache as the owner and reset all folders permissions to to 755 and files 644.  The site works but I get a n error in the downloader saying there aren't sufficient write permissions and I can't edit anything via FTP.

Answer (score 0):

Its not good to have 777 on all your folders as it makes it publicly accessible and changeable. Some can be 777, more so 755, and most cases 644

Get set the folders to the right permissions the easiest way is to use the Magento cleanup tool here:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/resetting_file_permissions

Scroll down a bit on that page to download the Magento Cleanup Tool

You can also reference the Magento installation cheat sheet Step 2 - Set file permissions:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-installation-cheat-sheet#step2

So I would set everything back to 644, and then run the cleanup tool.

Comment: The problem is if my folders are 755 i need to set the user to apache.  I then can't edit any of the files in FTP.  The only way I can do this is by adding my user as the owner.  If I do this Magento breaks unless the files are set to 777. I'm not sure what combination of permissions and ownership I should use to prevent having to use 777 but everything still works including FTP.

Answer (score 0):

Magento Permission can be set by running a file in the installation.For that you need to download the magento cleaup tool.

[Download Magento Cleanup Tool](http://realtuts.com/how-to-clear-magento-internal-server-error-after-installation/)